# Is there a way to run javascript on load before server side pageload?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

in my applciation (asp.net - using vb as the code behind language) the server side (vb) pageload code runs first, and when this completes it runs the javascript onload. Is there anyway to run the javascript onload first? My javascript gets the value of a variable from the parent window (uses iframes), and uses that to set controls in the child window. The pageload deals with the control set (if the value from the parent is a certain value, then different checkboxes will automatically be checked).

The only other solution to this issue I can think of is to check the value at the moment to see if the boxes are checked when another function to generate the page's html runs. The issue with this is that the function is called from javascript using pagemethods and needs to be shared, and due to this I am unable to check in the start of this function to see if the checkbox is checked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It makes no sense. The server-side code runs on *your* side of the Internet, and the JavaScript runs on the client machine *after* the result of the server side code has been transmitted to it.

Comment: which is why i was asking if anyone knew of any logical work around or a way to deal with this issue. what i believe to be the correct approach is to have the end of the javascript onload re call the server side to perform the same things the onload would have.

Comment: A problem like this is usually indicative of bad design.

Comment: There's no way to do what you're asking, because you don't need to do what you're asking. Modify the DOM on page load / use AJAX to post back to the server / any number of other options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, javascript always runs on the client after the server has finished sending the response to the client.

You'll have to change your javascript to run against the generated html.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is no.

However if I understand what you're trying to do, you want to modify controls based on a value from the server. Why not just send an AJAX request to get that value, then update the controls accordingly.

With that being said, it does seem like the architecture of your application is a bit in shambles so if all you need is a bandaid, maybe you can generate that server value, render it within an id or hidden input element, then read that value with your JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using it to get a value from the parent window you could use a bit of a workaround that I have used before.  From your parent window you could set the source of the iframe and append a query string on to it that would have your value.  Then from the page within the iframe you could check the querystring to get the value and then check your check boxes accordingly.

In the load pr prerender, depending on when you set your variable that you need, of your main page you could put something like `iframeWhatever.Attributes.Add("src", "../filepath/page.aspx?ValueNeeded=" + ValueNeeded.ToString)`

I am pretty sure that this would be able to do what you are currently trying to accomplish with javascript.